Любые действия в консоли с composer или artisan приводят к ошибке
Laravel 9. После создания собственных комманд в консоли - любые действия с composer или artisan приводят к ошибке:

In Macroable.php line 113:
  Method App\Console\Commands\CustomTask::isDeferred does not exist. 

composer update и php artisan cleaner не помогает - в консоле та же ошибка.
Работоспособность восстанавливаю только backup. Подскажите куда копать? Заранее благодарен!

Скорее всего вы разместили класс не там где надо в настроечных файлах Laravel. Чтобы не гадать нужно запустить консольную команду в отладочном режиме и пройтись по stack / error trace.

@ Daniel Protopopov . БЛАГОДАРЮ. Дайте пожалуйста ответ я отмечу как правльный. Нашел конечно ошибку в  настроечных файлах Laravel

Скорее всего вы разместили класс не там где надо в настроечных файлах Laravel. Чтобы не гадать нужно запустить консольную команду в отладочном режиме и пройтись по stack / error trace.
